# We have encountered an issue in Amount calculation when of user has locale Hungry(Hungarian) in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, community

We have a field named as `Amount` of type `Currency(16, 2)` on an sObject, User who is viewing this value on Visulaforce Page has locale `Hungarian(Hungry)`, on Visulaforce Page it displays space as thousand separator of Amount field even when we are using this field value as merge field.

For example:

Amount field has value `1500.00` in database then on Visualforce Page UI it displayed `1 500,00` for `Hungarian(Hungry)` & due to space in value we are unable to perform any calculation in expressions which results in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce displays currency format on view as per user local setting. 
So, we can't modify the standard binding of format as per user local setting in salesforce.